# not getting whole data by sqlmap

Tags: kali-linux, sql

```
$ sqlmap -u http://192.168.0.106/get_method/get_data/?id=1 -D get_method -T user --dump
```

[image]

But, my data

[image]

CSV also completely same as terminal picture

```
name,serial,password,timestamp
asdf,1,asdf,2021-03-23 13:35:00
```

Why I am not getting whole data by sqlmap?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh! Sorry my mistake

```
sqlmap -u http://192.168.0.106/get_method/get_data/?id=1 --dbs
```

I forgot `?id=1` for a moment. It is only giving me 1 data from server. While there's only single data giving me php file, So how can I get all data from server... That's why I was only getting single data in csv and terminal...